# create table as select with primary key in snowflake --need syntax

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know it works (when there is no select as)
`CREATE TABLE t1 (  dt1 date ,primary key (dt1)) ;`

I also know alter table works like below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t2 as (select current_date as dt1 ) ; 
alter TABLE t2  add primary key (dt1) ;
```

But I need a syntax for create table with PK when there is SELECT in Create Table. I am trying to convert existing code and other DB support Create Table as select with PK.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like you'd normally add a primary key:

```sql
create or replace transient table test_table (number_1 number primary key, number_2 number, number_3 number) as (
    select column1, column2, column3
    from
    values (1, 2, 3),
           (3, 4, 5)
)
;
```

**Results**

```
describe table TEST_TABLE;
-- +--------+------------+------+-----+-------+-----------+----------+
-- |name    |type        |kind  |null?|default|primary key|unique key|
-- +--------+------------+------+-----+-------+-----------+----------+
-- |NUMBER_1|NUMBER(38,0)|COLUMN|N    |NULL   |Y          |N         | --> Primary Key
-- |NUMBER_2|NUMBER(38,0)|COLUMN|Y    |NULL   |N          |N         |
-- |NUMBER_3|NUMBER(38,0)|COLUMN|Y    |NULL   |N          |N         |
-- +--------+------------+------+-----+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: If you see Teradata syntax, it allows you to --> create table t2 as (select * from t2 ) primary_index (col1) .  So we do not need to explicitly define columns on T2 and you can still create PK. I know snowflake does not enforce PK data, But I still wanted to implement it for performance reasons.

Comment: Perhaps update your question because that's not what you asked originally. Also update your question with what you've already attempted

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation for Variant Create Table syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax) it looks like the following should work:

```
 CREATE TABLE t1 ( dt1 Date, primary key (dt1))
 AS SELECT CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: But this is not going to solve my original problem. I need to create table as --> create temporary table temp1 as select * from table1. And let's say it table has col1 and col2 and I want to make col1 as PK, it will not work unless I explicitly provide all column name in temp1 table. Teradata supports adding PK after select and without explicitly adding column name while creating table.

Comment: This syntax is a single statement that you submit where you both define the PK AND provide the select statement that will be used to fill the table. As I read it's exactly what you are looking for. OR... is it that you are trying to do `SELECT *` without being explicit about your column list? If that's the case then there is no single statement solution to your problem. You'll have to explicitly list your column definitions and explicitly list your columns in your SELECT statement and match those two lists 1:1.